# How to read data from data file using infile statement?

Tags: sas, analytics

I am trying to read numeric data from the file. But I am to read it properly the output that I am getting from my SAS program is attached. I recently started learning SAS programming.

I am using SAS University Edition on the windows machine. I already tried by reading data in character as well as numeric formate.

```
data ds;
infile '/folders/myshortcuts/my_folder/exrate.sas7bdat';
input s ;
run;
```

I am expecting the same table to be as an output result.

Data File

[image]

Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 things you need to do:

1. Make sure that the folder you put the dataset in is accessible to the SAS University Edition VM. Did you follow the setup guide in full? Usually that directs you to set up a folder that becomes available within the VM as `/folders/myfolders`
2. Assign a library pointing to the folder using a libname statement.
3. Use a `set` statement to access the dataset, not an `infile` statement. The latter is for reading raw data like csv files.

The sas code should look like this:

```
libname mylib "/folders/myfolders"; /*Change this to point to your folder path if you're sure you've got the right one*/

data ds;
    set mylib.exrate(keep = s);
run;
```